# collectionView with pageControl in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have a tableView which contains a collectionView and a pageControl. I want to set the currentPage of the pageControl when I scroll through the collectionView. But I don't know how to do it when both the items are in tableView. How to do it?

Comment: have you tried this???
`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.collectionview.frame.size.width;
    int currentPage = self.collectionview.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
}`

Comment: yes but I dont know how to get instance of the repeating collection view

Comment: i cant understand tell me in detail.